# Streaming a frame capture using gstreamer

Tags: qt, gstreamer

How can I link a pipeline streaming a frame capture images using Gstreamer?

I am trying this:

```cpp
g_signal_connect(decoderBin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(onPadAdded), h264parse1);//_tee, recorderQueue,

qCCritical(VideoReceiverLog) << "link elements"<<_recorderValve<<decoderBin<<rtph264depay<<h264parse<<openh264dec<<videoconverts<<jpegenc<<appSinks_ ;

if (!gst_element_link_many( _recorderValve, decoderBin, h264parse, openh264dec, videoconverts, jpegenc, appSinks_, nullptr)) {  //decoderBin,videoconverts,h264parse
    qCCritical(VideoReceiverLog) << "Failed to link elements";
    return;
}
else{
    qCCritical(VideoReceiverLog) << "link elements Successfully";
    g_object_set(static_cast<gpointer>(appSinks_), "location", qPrintable("captured.jpg") , NULL);
}
```

But it results in corrupted file being created.

The file is saved, but he data is not stored.